# How do I go about solving this question?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, oxidation-state

[image]

So I've studied Redox concepts but in the exam we are asked questions like these.
How am I supposed to know what the reaction is going to be?
How do I go ahead and assume what oxidation state it's going to be and then form the reaction?
Do I need to have knowledge about how the reactants interact to answer these questions or is there something only based on redox concepts that I can use to answer this question?

Comment: Think about the products that result from that reaction. Usually, when bubbling chlorine gas over a sodium hydroxide solution, one would get two chlorine based products: chloride and hypochlorite. Here, the conditions are quite different: since the sodium hydroxide solution is both hot and concentrated, it provides a more oxidizing medium. Hence, you might get chloride and a form more oxidized than hypochlorite.

Comment: "Do I need to have knowledge about how the reactants interact to answer these questions". Yes, you need to.

Comment: How would you like a book title "How would I go about naming this book ?" ? BTW screenshots/photos of easy plain text are highly discouraged for multiple reasons.

Comment: Reaction of chlorine with hot hydroxide is easily available in textbooks or online resources.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I wanted to know if students all over the world use anything else - ideas/tricks/mnemonics that'll categorise particular reactions.

Comment: For example if we look at organic chemistry, most questions can be easily distinguished and categorised into SN1 & 2. This way it becomes easier to remember bigger chunk of information for competitive exams. Please just don't judge a person's questions without understanding the complete reasons. I couldn't rather googled this instead of posting it here right? There's obviously a reason I want it to be a discussion where I can see how other students deal with questions. For you it might be a simple question because you've explored the subject enough, for a beginner it isn't. @Poutnik

Comment: I appreciate the way Maurice has given the answer here.

Comment: Questions here are assumed to be well elaborated. If they are not, the OP can blame just himself for wrong assumptions of others, who do not know the background, circumstances and questionable hidden elaboration. Chemistry has a good set on main rules, a lot of empirical evidence to be learnt, and with this knowledge comes recognizing patterns that lay between empiriic knowledge and rules. I prefer teaching fishing to giving fish. Disproportionation of chlorine to -I/+I and -I/+V is such data to learn or pattern already known, depending on knowledge level. Wikipedia is full of great articles.

Comment: You are neither the first neither the last who asks here for tricks to learn chemistry. There is no simple trick. The only way not to memorize everything is to understand it and recognize patterns in behaviour. That takes time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you have to know that $\ce{Cl2}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$ react at low temperatures according to $$\ce{Cl2 + 2 NaOH -> NaCl + NaClO}$$ and that at high temperature, the hypochlorite $\ce{NaClO}$ gets disproportionated according to $$\ce{3 NaClO -> 2 NaCl + NaClO3}$$ There is no way of predicting it. It must be known. So b) is the good answer.

Note that the preceding reactions may be written with ions instead of sodium compounds.